# Why CSS3 transition is not working on set height of element using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I have written a snippet of code to create an accordion that you can see the code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lx2wj6ne/13/).

There is some HTML code:

```
<div class="accordion_holder">
  <div class="accordion_item">
    <div class="title" onclick="toggle_accordion(this);">
      title 1 here
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      content here
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion_item">
    <div class="title" onclick="toggle_accordion(this);">
      title 2 here
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      content 2 here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I have bellow CSS to simulate accordion transition:

```
.accordion_holder .content {
    height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: height 0.5s linear;
    -ms-transition: height 0.5s linear;
    -o-transition: height 0.5s linear;
    transition: height 0.5s linear;
}
```

And I am setting the height of content to `0px` or it's `offsetHeight` using this snippet of JavaScript code:

```
function toggle_accordion(clicked_element) {
  var father = closest_parent(clicked_element, 'accordion_item');
  console.log(father);
  var accordion_content = father.getElementsByClassName("content")[0];
  var destination = 0;

  var current_height = accordion_content.offsetHeight;

  if (current_height == 0)
  {
    accordion_content.style.height = "auto";
    destination = accordion_content.offsetHeight;

    accordion_content.style.height = "0px";
  }
  console.log("destination is:", destination);
  accordion_content.style.height = destination+"px";
}

/************************************
 ** Find Closest Parent with Class **
 ***********************************/
function closest_parent (current_element, class_name) {
    var parent = current_element.parentElement;
    if (parent) {
        if (parent.className.indexOf(class_name) >= 0)
        {
            //We found requested parent
            return parent;
        }
        else
        {
            return closest_parent (parent, class_name);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

It's working correctly to set the height of content element. when it is closing (set the height of Content element to `0px`), it will move smoothly and transition effect is working. but when it is opening (set the height of Content element to `offsetHeight`), Transition won't work.

Can you please guide me what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're setting the height to `auto` *and then* trying to get its `offsetHeight`.

Getting the `offsetHeight` [triggers a reflow](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a), so it's already going to layout the page and try to make a transition to `height: auto`; Since transitions to `height: auto` don't work, it's going to jump straight to the target height. Then, when you set the element's height to the value you got from `offsetHeight`, the element already has that height, so there will be no transition.

Two ways you could fix that:

A more hacky way is to turn the reflow triggered by `offsetHeight` to your favor: just try to get the value again after setting the height back to 0, triggering the reflow again:

```
if (current_height == 0)
  {
    accordion_content.style.height = "auto";
    destination = accordion_content.offsetHeight;

    accordion_content.style.height = "0px";
    // Here is the trick:
    accordion_content.offsetHeight // triggers a reflow
  }
```

Another way is to store the height of the contents of the accordion elements beforehand, so you just transition to that value. That can be tricky, especially if the contents of the accordion can change, but it's less dependent on esoteric browser behaviour.

Comment: Oh, I did not hear about Reflow before. thank you for your really nice guideline.